Zero stress in $z$ components for thin surfaces
We can write the stress tensor as:
\begin{equation}
  T=  \left [
    \begin{array}{ccc}
      \sigma_r & \tau_{r\theta} & \tau_{rz} \\ 
      \tau_{\theta r} & \sigma_\theta & \tau_{\theta z} \\ 
      \tau_{zr} & \tau_{z\theta} & \sigma_z
   \end{array}
  \right ]\end{equation} In most of the references they wrote that, for thin surfaces, the 3 components $\sigma_{\theta z} = \sigma_{z \theta} = \sigma_z\approx 0$. But there is no clear mathematical proof using thickness or trying to write the stress components as function of the pressure and thickness. Is there a good reference or a way to prove that?
